# Can you have a virtual top designated in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a photo gallery at the moment and the target on the img is set to `top: 0`.

The problem with this is that I have a fixed `nav` at the top. So when I click the image it displays correctly but the `nav` covers it.

When I tried adjusting where the image was anchored to when it's targeted, the whole CSS moved and the image moved *that* many pixels [below or above] away from where it was originally positioned on the page.

Is there anyway to create a "virtual top" where the image can be below the `nav` for viewing?

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    max-height: 100%;
    color: #171717;
    background-color: #000000;
    font-size: .9em;
}
nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 85px;
    margin: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10000;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: 0.8;
    font-size: .8em;
}
nav li {
    margin-top: 1em;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
}
nav li a {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #A3A3A3;
}
nav li a:hover {
    background-color: #A3A3A3;
    color: #171717;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 420px) {
    nav {
        margin-top: 0;
        height: 185px;
        margin: 1;
        padding: 0;
    }
    nav li {
        margin-top: 0;
        display: block;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
}
#maincontent {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 7em;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
#gallery-display {
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #000;
}
#gallery-display img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 500px;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}
#gallery-display[id^='image']:target img {
    top: 0;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 500px;
}
#gallery-display[id^="image"] img {
    position: absolute;
    top: -500px;
    border: 0;
    -moz-transition: top 0.5s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: top 0.5s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: top 0.5s ease-in;
    -o-transition: top 0.5s ease-in;
}
#gallery-slider-parent {
    background-color: #000;
    position: relative;
    width: 960px;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
}
#gallery-slider {
    background-color: #000;
    display: inline;
    width: 94%;
    float: left;
    height: 120px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#gallery-slider img {
    height: 75px;
    padding: 15px;
    float: none;
}
#gallery-slider img, #gallery-slider a {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<nav>
    <li><a href="/">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/">Photos</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/">About</a>
    </li>
</nav>

<div id="maincontent">
    <p id="title">Title of set</p>
    <div id="gallery-display">
        <div id="image-1">
            <img src="image1.jpg">
        </div>
        <div id="image-2">
            <img src="image2.jpg">
        </div>
        <div id="image-3">
            <img src="image3.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="gallery-slider-parent">
        <div id="gallery-slider">
            <a href="#image-1"><img src="image1.jpg" height="75"></a>
            <a href="#image-2"><img src="image2.jpg" height="75"></a>
            <a href="#image-3"><img src="image3.jpg" height="75"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Added suggestions I've tried - that didn't work:

With the `#maincontent` with `position: relative` the `nav` still covers the image

http://jsfiddle.net/7kHBY/2/

Comment: If I'm not mistaken adding `position: relative; margin-top: 85px` on `#maincontent` should solve your issue. All elements (B) with `position: absolute` within `position: relative` element (A) should treat elements A as 0,0. (Can't really say if it will solve your issue without JS that's adding the additional styles). If you could please create working fiddle it would be helpful.

Comment: So I guess you want the page to go back to the top then?

Comment: @DannyvanHolten I want the page to stay where it is when the thumbnail is clicked.

Comment: @DannyvanHolten I just thought of a better way of explaining it. I would like the bottom of the `nav` to be the relative top.

Comment: If you want the page not to move it's impossible as your navbar is fixed. you're linking to an anchor in your website. If you link to an anchor in a website this will put the anchor on the absolute top. The only way to fix this is to put your anchor exactly 85 pixels above the actual picture.

But then you can't as you want to target the picture. Only other option I see is to give the picture padding-top: 85px;

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to create a virtual top, and I found 2 solutions to solve that:

1. Insert the gallery into a DIV and set it with the `top:85px`. Sometimes this method is not perfect because you will need to change all the types of content, so all the pages will need to have the content into a DIV with the same `top` declaration.
2. Insert the fixed nav bar into a DIV with `position:relative` and `top:85px`. It will create a virtual height. Then keep the nav bar with `position:fixed`.

Comment: JSFiddle with suggestion added

Answer (score 0):

So Yes, this is the only possible option.

http://jsfiddle.net/4hDrW/

You're linking to an anchor. And as the anchor is the target (and you can't change it) there is no other option then giving the target a padding-top: 85px;

Normally linking to an anchor put's it to the absolute top op the page. Which isn't what you want. Either you can change the target, which requires edditing your entire code.

Or just putting this code into your page

```
#gallery-display img {
    padding-top: 85px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 500px;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```